# tablesorter formatting issues between numbers with commas and numbers without them

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a price field and a total amount field:
Price field has a value of 0.9999900 or 0.9000000 Total amount can be 10,000.00 or 1,000,000.00. I am using tablesorter library to sort the table.

Issue is If I set s like below (total amount sorting works fine)

```
s=s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z ]/g),"");
```

If I set s like below (price sorting works fine)

```
s=s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z. ]/g),"");
```

But I cant get both to work at the same time.. What am I missing:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "digit",
    is: function(s,table) {
        var c = table.config;
        s=s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z ]/g),"");
        return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s,c);
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z ]/g),""));
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a work around the different columns:**

1) I made both columns points to different functions in tablesorter, that way I could have both price and total amount work their own way.

Under tablesorter I modified the header to have digits for total amount column and thousands for "total amount" column.

```
headers: {8: { sorter: 'digit' },13: { sorter: 'thousands' }}
```

Where 8, 13 are my column numbers on my table.

2)For "Total amount" columns number 8, i used id:digits

3)For "Price" column number 13, I used a custom parser id:"thousands"

**Tablesorter code for both included below**

**id: "digit"-->Existing code in the Tablesorter library**

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "digit",
    is: function(s,table) {
        var c = table.config;
        s=s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z ]/g),"");
        return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s,c);
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z ]/g),""));
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

**id: 'thousands'-->Custom table sorter added to the tablesorter lib.**

```
ts.addParser({ 
    id: 'thousands',
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) {
        return s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9\/A-Za-z. ]/g),"");
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
});

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            6: {//zero-based column index
                sorter:'thousands'
            }
        }
    });
});
```